# When was Menachem Davidovitch's tikun published?

Tags: sefer-torah, safrus

As has been discussed here in the past, the [modern layout for a Sefer Torah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/43748/5459) comes from Mencahem Davidovitch, a 20th-century sofer. When did he first publish it and where? (ie, did he publish a book or was it a periodical of some kind).