# Are all Vavei Ha'amudim Sifre Torah created today, identical?

Tags: sefer-torah, safrus

There is a standardized format of writing Torah scrolls called *Vavei Ha'amudim*. The concept is that the majority of columns in the Torah (except for 6 places) should start with the letter *vav*.

[This answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/43751/5275) gives a bit more detail on why this format was done as well as its controversy. However, it seems that the concept is to create Sifrei Torah to match Davidovich's Tikkun format.

Considering that the main requirement to conform to the format is that the letter vav appears at the top of the column. Considering that almost every verb usage in the Torah has a *vav hahipuch*, it's not hard to do this.

Are all Vavei Ha'amudim Sifrei Torah that were created after Davidovich's latest standard identical? If not, how many current Sofrim (approximate percentage is fine) these days are using Davidovich's format as opposed to just creating any other *Vavei Ha'amudim* standard?

Comment: Seemingly a Sofer will just use whatever he prefers or what his client asks him to. There's no halakhic issues at play here whatsoever.

Comment: Here's a Sofer who wrote a Torah not according to the Davidovich layout: http://lavlor.blogspot.com/2013/08/how-many-lines-should-my-torah-scroll.html So no they are not all identical.

Comment: Using a particular layout is more a matter making it easier for the sofer to make sure that the columns are correct and that a particular column (most probably) does not have an error in it.

Comment: If I may be nitpicky: except for 5 places. One of the six exceptions isn't an exception after all [(בי-ה שמ**ו**)](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/36957/9682). But I think we can all agree that all (kosher) Sifrei Torah begin their first column the same way.

Comment: No. My shul has a *vavei ha'amudim* Sefer Torah that does not match the format of my tikun kor'im.

Comment: @sci Do those Torahs postdate Davidovich's Tikkun?

Answer (score 1):

In both shuls that I daven in, 1 out of the 5 Sifrei Torah have a *Vavei Ha'amudim* layout that diverges from the classic Davidovich<sup>*</sup> setup. (It gets really embarrassing when you rely on the page layout for tricky trop sequences, and then the Sefer has the *wrong* layout.)

Whether those 2 are identical I cannot say.

<sup>* Four weeks ago (23 Sivan 5777) R' Menachem Davidovich of *Vavei Ha'amudim - Blue Tikkun* fame passed away at age 89. [Source](http://www.bhol.co.il/120519/%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%9D-%D7%A9%D7%9C-%D7%94%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%99-%D7%9E%D7%A0%D7%97%D7%9D-%D7%93%D7%95%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A5-%D7%96%D7%A6%D7%9C.html)</sup>

Comment: Boruch dayan emes

Comment: Do those Torahs postdate Davidovich's Tikkun?

Comment: @DoubleAA - yes, these are all of recent vintage (almost new, as in 5 - 15 years old). 
In my youth we had "ancient" Sifrei Torah (brought over by immigrants/escapees from Germany) - no 2 Seforim were of the same size (lines/per page) or layout.